# SQL query -> LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to write this query using LINQ?

I really can't get it.

```
Select tblKeywords.Keyword AS CoursesKeyWords
From
    tblCourse_KeyWord
Join
    tblCourses ON tblCourses.ID = tblCourse_KeyWord.Course_ID
Join 
    tblKeywords ON tblKeywords.ID = tblCourse_KeyWord.KeyWord_ID
Where 
    tblCourses.ID = 1
```

I've got three tables

[EntityFramework classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGhZf.png)

[image]

It's relation many to many (isn't it?)

And that's what i want to do is:
Find all keywords for specified course.

I'm looking for the easiest way to do it.
That query (in first post) - it looks like it works correclty, but i couldn't rewrite it in Linq.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. I'm sure people will answer this question soon, but honestly, Stack Overflow's purpose is not to write code for you.

Comment: Also specify if you are using EF and if so show the models so we can look at the navigation properties

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has no use past answering this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have these tables / views: tblCourse_KeyWord, tblCourses, tblKeywords mapped to a context, let it be "ctx"

the result would be:

```
from p in ctx.tblKeywords
join rel in ctx.tblCourse_KeyWord
on new { KeyWord_ID = (int?)p.ID, CourseId = 1 } equals new { KeyWord_ID = (int?)rel.KeyWord_ID, CourseId = rel.Course_ID }
select p.Keyword
```

*(from what can i see, you don't need to perform the second join because you can put the condition (Course_Id = 1) from the join with the relation.)*

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a context named `db` and all names are same as in SQL. The exact way to translate the query would be like this:

```
db.tblCourse_KeyWord.Join(db.tblCourse, 
                          c_kw => c_kw.Course_ID, 
                          c => c.ID,
                          (c_kw, c) => new { CourseKW = c_kw, Course = c})
                    .Where(x => x.Course.ID == 1)
                    .Join(db.tblKeywords,
                          x => x.CourseKW.Keyword_ID,
                          k => k.ID,
                          (x, k) => new { CoursesKeyWord = k.Keyword });
```

But it can be simplified (as [George Lica answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901790/5679064) suggested) to:

```
db.tblKeywords.Join(db.tblCourse_KeyWord,
                    k => new { KID = k.ID, CID = 1 },
                    c_kw => new { KID = c_kw.Keyword_ID, CID = c_kw.Course_ID},
                    (k, c_kw) => k.Keyword);
```